# Migrating AI Platform Notebooks from standalone VPC to Share VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have a bunch of projects running standalone AI Platform Notebooks with their own VPCs.  I want to move them to a Shared VPC. Normally with GCE, you can take a snapshot, delete the VM, create a new VM on the new Shared VPC, and you're off.  However, since AI Platform Notebooks is a managed service, I'm curious how this would work.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Craig, with Shared VPC you have 2 projects: Host + Consumer Project, where Host is where the subnet/VPC exists. Are you saying that you will migrate Notebooks to a different project within your org or only change the VPC ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow the common process to migrate a GCE instance; however, there is an additional step, after creating your new legacy notebook it's required to [register](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/registering-legacy-notebooks) it within the AI Platform Notebooks API.

There is another option to migrate a notebook instance to a new AI Platform Notebooks instance, you can find information about this workaround [in here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/registering-legacy-notebooks#migrate-to-new-instance).

From a network perspective, there is a Beta feature to [migrate a VM between networks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/migrating-interfaces-between-networks), nonetheless, it will depend on your use-case, in there you can see the supported scenarios.